# VirtualBox上でLAMP環境を構築したい

Tags: centos, apache

VirtualBox上でLAMP環境を構築したい。
以下の環境でOSやミドルウェアをインストールしました。

- OS:Centos 6.5
- PHP 5.3
- Apache　2.2
- mysql 5.1
- Perl
- phpMyAdmin-4.5.0.2  ：「/var/www/html 」の下
- VMの固定IP：192.168.3.5

下記内容でindex.phpを作って、

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

http://192.168.3.5 へアクセスしてphpinfoを確認しましたので、PHPは使えます。

また、仮想の端末から、mysqlへの接続ができます。

問題（１）
http://localhost へアクセスしたら、

下記のエラーにてページ表示ができません

> •Web アドレス http://localhost  が正しいか確かめてください。

問題（２）

http://192.168.3.5/phpMyAdmin へアクセスしたら、

下記のエラーにてphpMyAdminのログイン画面が表示されません。

> Forbidden
>   You don't have permission to access /phpMyAdmin/ on this server.
>   Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at 192.168.3.5 Port 80

/etc/sysconfig/iptables　設定ファイルに、以下の一行を追加して、iptablesサービスを再起動しても上記エラーを解消できません。

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

解決方法を教えていただけますか。
よろしくお願いします。

主な設定は下記の通りです。

(1) /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.confの変更
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
　  
(2) /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf下記内容で新規作成
    [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
(3) /var/www/html/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.phpの変更
    $cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'hogehoge';  
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie'; 
    $cfg['Lang'] = 'ja-utf-8';

(4) phpMyAdminの所有者を変更
    chown -R root.apache /var/www/html/phpmyadmin/

(5) /var/www/html/define.phpでデータベースを設定する
    define("DB_SERVER_NAME", "localhost");      
    define("DB_USER_NAME", "root");     
    define("DB_USER_PASS", "testpass");     
    define("DB_NAME", "testdb");

Comment: 質問の範囲が広すぎます。もう少し質問を限定してください。

Comment: とりあえず、『PHP 環境構築』とかググると、環境構築方法は出てくると思います。ただ、CentはPHPのversionが古かった気がするので、手動installした方が良かった気がします。

Comment: http://192.168.3.5/phpMyAdmin/index.php にアクセスするとどうなりますか？ httpd.confとかphp.iniとか config.inc.phpとか設定が出来てないと思います。

Comment: 192.168.3.5/phpMyAdmin/index.php にアクセスしても同じエラーです。

Comment: いろんな可能性が考えられるので回答は難しいでしょうね。トラブルシューティングの手助けが必要でしたら、自身が「やったこと」を省略せずに出来るだけ具体的に書いてみてください。設定ファイルを変更したのであれば変更した内容を、パーミッションを変えたのであれば実行したコマンドを書くと言った具合です。あとログファイルにメッセージは出力されていませんか？見ている方にもっとヒントを提示できれば回答が付きやすくなると思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
整理してから質問内容に追加します。

Answer (score 1):

インストール後の環境設定はやりました？　phpMyAdmin.conf とか conf.inc.phpとか。

403エラーに関しては phpMyAdminのインストール時に生成されるapacheの設定ファイル( phpMyAdmin.conf )ではインストールしたサーバーからのアクセスしか許可していないのでコレが原因だと思います。

/etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.confを編集し127.0.0.1以外のip addrからのアクセスを許可してください。

その他設定はインストールされた環境(pathとかその他諸々)に合わせて設定してください。

Comment: サイト情報を参考してphpMyAdmin.conf とか conf.inc.phpを設定しました。
正しいかどうかは分かりません。
一つ気になる点はあります。
/var/www/html/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx';
その値はどこを参照して設定すればいいですか？

Comment: 外部に公開しないのであればhogeでもfuga でも何でもいいです。あなたしか知らない文字列を設定してください。cookie値を暗号化・複合化するときのパスフレーズになります

Comment: ありがとうございます。
設定内容を再度確認してから報告します。

Answer (score 1):

`/etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf` で全てのクライアントからの接続を拒否する設定になってますね。

`Order Deny,Allow` に変えて見てください。

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/phpMyAdmin">
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: ご回答有難うございます。
Order Deny,Allow に変えてみましたが、同じエラーです。

Comment: /var/www/html/phpMyAdmin/のパーミッションを確認してください。apacheユーザーに対するアクセス権はどうなってますか？

Comment: chown -R root.apache /var/www/html/phpMyAdmin/ で phpMyAdminの所有者を変更しました。

Comment: /var/www/html/phpMyAdmin/のパーミッション 755 です。

Comment: 変なところはないですね。設定ファイル変更後 httpd はリスタートしましたか？

Comment: あとSELinuxは有効にしてますか？ 確認方法は `sudo getenforce` を実行して enforcing と表示されれば有効なので `sudo setenforce 0` で無効化してみてください。

Comment: 毎回設定ファイル変更後に httpd はリスタートしました。
setenforce 0で無効化してからも状況は変わりません。
難しいですね。

Comment: もし貴方と同じ現象を再現する手順を質問に追記してもらえれば、私の方でも試すことは出来ますがどうでしょうか？

Comment: お手間かけしてすみません。。
設定内容を再度確認して、192.168.3.5/phpMyAdmin/index.php にアクセスしたら、「PHP 5.5+ is required」のメッセージが表示されました。
yum でインストールしたのはPHP５．３．３です。

Comment: rpmforgeのリポジトリを使用して、古いバージョンのphpmyadminをインストールし直しました。
http://192.168.3.5/phpmyadmin/　アクセスしたら、下記エラーが表示されました。
MySQLのメッセージ:  #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) 
phpmyadmin再インストール後、confic.inc.phpとphpmyadmin.confを設定しましたのに。

Comment: 進展合ったようですね。phpMyAdminはインストールが面倒なのでエラーを一つずつ潰していくしかないですね。エラーはMySQLのアクセス権不足のようですが、MySQLに `root@localhost` ユーザのパスワードや権限を設定してますか？ちょうど同じエラーについての記事があったので参考にしてみてください→ http://www.goofoo.jp/2011/11/1457

Comment: 有難うございます。すぐに解決できそうもないです。別件で忙しいから、落ち着いてからまたエラーを潰していきます。

Comment: 下記のようにconfig.inc.phpを作り直してから、192.168.3.5/phpmyadmin　へ　アクセスできました。
(1) cp config.sample.inc.php config.inc.php　
(2) chmod 660 config.inc.php
(3) $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';→$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'http';

参考記事→http://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/991973.html

有難うございました。